# Is there an in-editor thread-tracking tool that shows each thread's position in source code?

Tags: java, multithreading, trace, bytecode

I'm wondering if there are any existent tools out there that allow a user to track the progress of each thread (like stepping through source code in a IDE's debugger) in-editor? I'm not looking for tools that debug individual threads during runtime - rather, a tool that shows what happened during unimpeded execution **after** a program has executed? A record of each thread's progress would be taken and then the user could 'replay' the program's execution step-by-step.

I've mocked up a snapshot of what I'm imagining, in-editor:

[image]

I'm aware of tools like VisualVM that show a Gantt chart style representation of threads' execution, although I'm specifically interested in in-editor visualisations as described, where the thread's (at least approximate) position in source code is shown.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but if the program were run on a system that has more than one CPU core, I _imagine_ that obtaining a meaningful serialization of all of the program's loads and stores would be a major technological challenge. The reason being, CPU cores provide hardware means for "single-stepping" the instructions that they execute, but memory systems generally do not provide any such means

Comment: I'm led to believe it's doable in Java using the ASM library, although I'm not so interested in how one might implement it - rather, whether any tools that do this (or something closely related) already exist

Comment: This assumes that there was something like a global time in respect to program execution flow, even on a source code level, that all threads agree on. The reason why it is so hard to do multithreading right, is precisely that this assumption is wrong. Even when we assume that your shared variables are all declared `volatile`, your last `++` operator is non-atomic but consists of a read, update, and write. How should a tool visualize overlapping execution of these three operations at the single source code expression? And how helpful is that without seeing the values of the variables?

Comment: Hi @Holger, thanks for your thoughts. Perhaps I'm missing something, but the tool I'm imagining isn't so concerned by the precise operations of a thread at any moment  and therefore, the atomicity of operations on any given source code line isn't an issue. It's only responsibility would be to update to a different line in the source code depending on what is currently being executed, giving an approximation of the thread's location in the execution of the code

Comment: @Holger I'd be interested if you could point me to a resource to understand what you mean with respect to the mistaken assumption of 'global time' - not quite sure I follow

Comment: You may study Java’s [Memory Model](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4). You may start with the examples given in the introduction.